# equivalence of any two polynomials of same degree

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, inequality

Let $P$ and $Q$ be two polynomials of same degree with real coefficients. Assume that $P$ and $Q$ have no real roots. It seems to me that $P$ and $Q$ are equivalent in the sense that there are some positive constants $c$ and $C$ (depending only on the degree and coefficients of $P$ and $Q$) such that $cP(x)\le Q(x)\le CP(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. My proof is based on the fact $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ is equal to the quotient of the leading coefficients. Is this statement and my proof correct? Can we generalize this statement in any ways? Are there any text books containing such a statement?

Comment: The statement is, but you haven't given a proof, and I don't know what you mean by the limit. What if $P(x)=x^2+10^{10^{10}}$ and $Q(x) = x^2+1$. How does the limit shed light on these constants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and the limits
$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$, $\lim_{x \to -\infty}$ exist, then $f$ is bounded. Apply this in turn to $f= \frac{P}{Q}$ and $\frac{Q}{P}$.